# Percentage of annual group total by subcategory

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, reshape2

I am trying to transform a dataframe into summary data of yearly totals and percentage breakdowns by subcategory. For example, if I have this data:

```
name year prod_type prod_color revenue
    a 2012       car        red    1000
    b 2012       car       blue    2000
    c 2012      boat        red    4000
    d 2012     plane       blue    5000
    a 2014      boat      green    9000
    b 2014       car        red    2000
    c 2014     plane       blue    6000
    a 2014     plane       blue   10000
```

And I want to create a table that looks like this:

```
 name year yr_total_rev pct_car_rev pct_boat_rev pct_plane_rev pct_red_car_rev pct_blue_car_rev
1    a 2012         1000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
2    a 2014        19000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
3    b 2012         2000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
4    b 2014         2000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
5    c 2012         4000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
6    c 2014         6000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
7    d 2012         5000          NA           NA            NA              NA               NA
```

Except the NA's are the percentages of "yr_total_rev" for each name/year pair--i.e. for a in 2012, car revenue would be 100%, but in 2014, it'd be 0% while boat and plane revenue would be 50%, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help you might have!

*Sample data below:*

```
df <- data.frame("name"=c(letters[1:4], c(letters[1:3], "a")), 
                 "year"=c(rep(2012,4), rep(2014, 4)),
                 "prod_type"=c("car","car","boat","plane","boat","car","plane","plane"),
                          "prod_color"=c("red","blue","red","blue","green","red","blue","blue"),
                 "revenue"=c(1000,2000,4000,5000,9000,2000,6000, 10000))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've joined three separate summaries in the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat.summary = df %>% group_by(name, year) %>% 
  summarise(yr_total=sum(revenue)) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% group_by(name, year, prod_type) %>% 
      summarise(rev=sum(revenue)) %>% 
      group_by(name, year) %>% 
      mutate(Percent=rev/sum(rev)) %>%
      select(-rev) %>% 
      spread(prod_type, Percent)) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% group_by(name, year, prod_type, prod_color) %>% 
      summarise(rev=sum(revenue)) %>% 
      group_by(name, year) %>% 
      mutate(Percent=rev/sum(rev)) %>%
      unite(type_color, prod_type, prod_color) %>% 
      select(-rev) %>% 
      spread(type_color, Percent))
```

> ```
>     name  year yr_total      boat   car     plane boat_green boat_red car_blue car_red plane_blue
> 1      a  2012     1000        NA     1        NA         NA       NA       NA       1         NA
> 2      a  2014    19000 0.4736842    NA 0.5263158  0.4736842       NA       NA      NA  0.5263158
> 3      b  2012     2000        NA     1        NA         NA       NA        1      NA         NA
> 4      b  2014     2000        NA     1        NA         NA       NA       NA       1         NA
> 5      c  2012     4000 1.0000000    NA        NA         NA        1       NA      NA         NA
> 6      c  2014     6000        NA    NA 1.0000000         NA       NA       NA      NA  1.0000000
> 7      d  2012     5000        NA    NA 1.0000000         NA       NA       NA      NA  1.0000000
> ```

This can be shortened a bit by writing a function:

```
fnc = function(...) {
  df %>% group_by(!!!quos(...)) %>% 
    summarise(rev=sum(revenue)) %>% 
    group_by(name, year) %>% 
    mutate(Percent=rev/sum(rev))
}

dat.summary = fnc(name, year) %>% select(-Percent) %>% 
  left_join(fnc(name, year, prod_type) %>%
              select(-rev) %>% 
              spread(prod_type, Percent)) %>% 
  left_join(fnc(name, year, prod_type, prod_color) %>%
              unite(type_color, prod_type, prod_color) %>% 
              select(-rev) %>% 
              spread(type_color, Percent))
```

Comment: This is so awesome! Thank you!